# Optimal method for nodejs to hand of image from database to browser

Tags: node.js, oracle

the end result that I need is to send multiple images to a web browser from a database.

The images are stored as blobs.

I know I can stream them out of the database and into a file and then I could just give the url to the file.

I also know I can hand off base64 string to the browser so it can render the image.

My question is which option is the most optimal? Or best practice? Keep in mind that if I go the stream method, I would have to check to see if the image has changed since the last time I displayed it...and if it has changed then I have to restream it out of the database.

I have been playing with the oracldb for node js and was able to successfully extract one blob into a file but I am also having trouble streaming multiple files.

This is a two question post:

Which is the most optimal:
 1. Send Base64 string - I kind of like this method because i dont have to worry about streaming out the file and checking if it has changed since it is coming straight from the databse. My concern is can the browser/nodejs handle it? I know those strings can be very large. I could also be sending more than one image at a time.

2. Stream the blobs into files.

The second part question is how can i get multiple blobs out below is my code on streaming just one file, i found this example from github lobstream1.js

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oracle/node-oracledb/master/examples/lobstream1.js
```

Focusing on the code:

```
// Stream a LOB to a file
var  dostream = function(lob, cb) {
  if (lob.type === oracledb.CLOB) {
    console.log('Writing a CLOB to ' + outFileName);
    lob.setEncoding('utf8');  // set the encoding so we get a 'string' not a 'buffer'
  } else {
    console.log('Writing a BLOB to ' + outFileName);
  }

  var errorHandled = false;

  lob.on(
    'error',
    function(err) {
      console.log("lob.on 'error' event");
      if (!errorHandled) {
        errorHandled = true;
        lob.close(function() {
          return cb(err);
        });
      }
    });
  lob.on(
    'end',
    function() {
      console.log("lob.on 'end' event");
    });
  lob.on(
    'close',
    function() {
      // console.log("lob.on 'close' event");
      if (!errorHandled) {
        return cb(null);
      }
    });

  var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(outFileName);
  outStream.on(
    'error',
    function(err) {
      console.log("outStream.on 'error' event");
      if (!errorHandled) {
        errorHandled = true;
        lob.close(function() {
          return cb(err);
        });
      }
    });

  // Switch into flowing mode and push the LOB to the file
  lob.pipe(outStream);
};
```

Fixed spooling out images with this method, I did change the dostream a bit.

```
for(var x = 0; x<result.rows.length;x++)
        {
          outputFileName = x + '.jpg';
          console.log(outputFileName);
          console.log(x);

          var lob = result.rows[x][0];
          dostream(lob,outputFileName);
//        cb(null,lob);
        }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm actually working on a related blog post at the moment. This isn't the answer, but have a look at this demo app: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v6rp4g7ytmsdi23/file_app_buffering.zip?dl=0 1) Unzip 2) Look in sql-scripts and run to create table 3) edit /config files as needed 4) run npm install 5) run node . or node index.js. This technique is the simplest as it does NOT use streaming, it buffers in Node.js instead. I'll be providing streaming examples next. As for caching, you could cache in Node.js (provided you had the memory) and use CQN or polling to invalidate the cache.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you very much for blog post on Oracle API using node it is actually what I am using and has been very helpful. Does my solution on streaming files look okay? Is there a better way of going about this? I will give your example a test today.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use case? How many Node.js instances do you have and how much memory does each have access to? What's the max, min, and average image size? How many distinct images are there? How many concurrent users do you have? How often are the images updated? Do the end users have to have the latest version all the time (is it critical)? There are different approaches you could consider based on the answers to those questions. Streaming as you're doing is the most efficient and scalable but it adds complexity to the code base when compared to just buffering in Node.js.

Comment: Personally, I don't see any value in the base64 encoding, but I may be misunderstanding something. The only advantage I see with writing the images to files in Node.js is that you can use the static middleware to serve and cache the images. I do see value in caching images in Node.js so you don't have to revisit the database if it's not needed. But caching the images on you're own (rather than using static middleware) isn't too difficult and may provide more flexibilty in terms of invaliating the cache.

Comment: @DanMcGhan 
Total Node.js instances = 1
Memory will roughly be 3GB of RAM
Max image size maybe 4 mb, avg I would say 3MB
Distinct images could be 100's maybe even 1000's just depends on how many images are added to the database.
Concurrent users just 10 or so users. It is all internal so the outside world wont have access to the images.
Images are hardly ever updated, once set they stay unless something out of the ordinary happens.
It is very critical to have the images up to date.

I look forward to your final solution, for now I'll stream them thanks to your efficient comment.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail! Here's a follow-up... On a given page in the app, how many images might a single user be looking at at one time? In other words, are there pages that display 10s or 100s of images at once? Or are users generally just looking at say one to a few images at a time?

Comment: That is correct, users will only request say 10 images at once. 
So it could be that at one point...15 users might ask nodejs to serve up to them 10 images maximum. I've built my sql to compare dates so I am not always streaming images out of the db, now it will only happen if the image has been modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given all the detail you provided in subsequent comments including the average image size, number of distinct images, memory available to Node.js, number of concurrent users, and the fact that it's "very critical to have the images up to date", here's my initial take...

For the first implementation, stick to the KISS principle and avoid over-engineering. Disable [browser caching](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#cache-control) and don't cache images in Node.js. Instead, rely on the driver and Oracle Database to do the heavy lifting for you.

As for the table storing the images, try to use SecureFile LOBs over BasicFile LOBs (they are known to perform better) if possible. Also, look at the caching options available to both (CACHE, CACHE READS, and NOCACHE). Consider enabling the CACHE READS option based on your stated workload, but work with your DBA to ensure the buffer cache is sized appropriately so you will not impact others.

You can rely on the connection pool's connection request queue to help control how many people are fetching files concurrently. In fact, you might want to create a separate pool just for this purpose so that people fetching LOBs aren't blocking people doing other things in the application. For example, let's say you normally have one connection pool with 10 connections. You could create two connection pools with 5 connections each (use the [connection pool cache](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connpoolcache) to make this easy). Then, in the code path that fetches lobs, use the lob pool and use the other pool for everything else.

Given this setup, I'd also recommend NOT streaming the LOBs. Using the driver's ability to buffer the LOBs in Node.js will greatly simplify the code and you should have plenty of memory given such a small number of concurrent users/file fetches.

The biggest problem with this scenario that the images are pretty large and they'll always be flowing from the database through Node.js to the browser. But since you'll be on an internal network, this might not be much of a problem. If it does turn out to be a problem, you can start to add caching in either the browser or Node.js based on what makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do something like tiling or the base64 inline encoding, each image needs its own URL, so each invocation of node-oracledb would return just one image.  You could do some kind of caching by writing to disk, but this seems extra IO - you will need to test to measure your own system's performance and memory requirements.  Regarding accessing multiple images in node-oracledb there's some code in https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1041#issuecomment-459002641 that may be useful.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thank you for your example that was dealing with a clob and didn't spit it out to a file but it helped me for sure. I ended up doing this:


for(var x = 0; x<result.rows.length;x++)
        {
          outputFileName = x + '.jpg';

          var lob = result.rows[x][0];
          dostream(lob,outputFileName);
        }

And changing up the dostream function a bit and I was successfully able to write all my images. I can do another for loop on the col to get all col so this is great.

Does this look okay?